# Does the following isomorphism hold true for modules: $(M\cap N)/(aM\cap N)\cong (0:_Ma)\cap N ?$

Tags: ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, modules, free-modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $N$ be a submodule of an $R$-module $M$  such that for each $a\in R$, $$aN=aM\cap N~~\text{and}~~M/aM\cong (0:_Ma)$$ where $(0:_Ma)=\{m\in M|am=0\}$ a submodule of $M$.  Is there any such isomorphism like $$(M\cap N)/(aM\cap N)\cong (0:_Ma)\cap N ?$$

I was using the Second Isomorphism Theorem and the modular law to examine $N/(aM\cap N)$ and I obtained the following:
$$N/(aM\cap N)\cong (N+aM)/aM=(M\cap N+aM)/aM\cong (M\cap N)/(M\cap aM\cap N)=(M\cap N)/(aM\cap N).$$ Now the last expression is tempting me to conclude that $$(M\cap N)/(aM\cap N)\cong (0:_Ma)\cap N!$$ since $M/aM\cong (0:_Ma)$.  I need some guidance whether this is wrong or right.

Comment: What is $(M/Ma)\cap N$?

Comment: I mean $(\frac{M}{Ma})\cap N$, the intersection between the quotient $M/Ma$ and the sub module $N$.

Comment: But that does not make sense: these are subsets of different modules!

Comment: Note that $M/aM\cong B$ for some submodule $B$ of $M$

Comment: The fact that $M/aM$ is isomorphic to some submodule of $M$ is not helping: it can be isomorphic to *several* submodules and you have to choose a particular isomorphism to do the “intersection".

Comment: The group law is sum or product?